# Theorem 6.19 in baby Rudin.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

The theorem (page 132) is:

> Suppose $\varphi$ is a strictly increasing continuous function that maps an interval $[ A, B]$ onto $[ a, b]$. Suppose $\alpha$ is monotonically increasing on $[ a, b]$ and $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$. Define $\beta$ and $g$ on $[ A, B]$ by 
>   $$ \beta(y) = \alpha \left( \varphi(y) \right), \qquad g(y) = f \left( \varphi(y) \right). $$
>   Then $g \in \mathscr{R}(\beta)$ and 
>   $$ \int_A^B g \ \mathrm{d} \beta =  \int_a^b f \ \mathrm{d} \alpha. $$.

So $\varphi$ has to be a strictly increasing continuous function. In the proof of the Sophomore's Dream https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream , the substiution $x = \varphi(u) = e^{-\frac{u}{n+1}}$ is used, which is a decreasing, continuous function. How is this so?

Comment: What is your question? The function $u\to x$ defined by this formula is decreasing since $dx/du<0$. Is this substitution somehow related to $\phi$ in the proof?

Comment: Isn't $\varphi(u) = e^{-\frac{u}{n+1}}$ here?

Comment: What is theorem 6.19, for those of us who don't have the book handy?

Comment: Their question is probably how can we use the theorem if our function is decreasing (rather than strictly increasing).

Comment: Omg best user name ever ^

Comment: Haha, thanks :)

Comment: Can you please post the relevant page from Rudin?

Comment: The theorem is also true for a decreasing change of variable. All you have to do is apply Rudin's theorem with $x=-\phi(u)$ and then remove the minus sign and flipping the order of the limits in the integral.